# Add class to one cell in header Yii2 GridView

Tags: gridview, header, yii2

How to add class to only one cell in header in GridView

I need code like this:

```
<table><tr><th>1</th><th class="big-border">2</th><th></th></tr></table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use headerOptions

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'summaryOptions' => ['class' =>'dfenx_pagination_summary',],
    'pager' => ['options' => ['class'=> 'pagination pull-right']],
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        //'tipo',
        ['attribute' => 'your_Attribute',    
            'label' => 'your_label',             
            'headerOptions' => ['class'=>'big-border',],
        ],

        .......
```